# how to continue running test ingnoring failure

Tags: php, phpstorm

How to run unit test ignoring failure in PhpStorm?

I am running unit test with code coverage in PhpStorm, execution stops when it encounters a failure.

Is there a way to continue execution ignoring failure?

Comment: https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html --- `stopOnFailure="false"` -- try it.